# finding intersecting shapes in R using shapefiles

Tags: r, polygon, shapefile

I have two shapefiles

shapefile1 and shapefile2

I want to find shapes which are intersecting with each other and then want to write new shapefile using it . I wrote some r code to find the same but somehow it is giving me exact same value as shapefile1 here's my code below.

```
shapefile1 <- st_read(shapefile1)
shapefile2 <- st_read(shapefile2)

intersecting_shapes <- terra::intersect(shapefile1,shapefile2)

intersecting_shapes <- vect(intersecting_shapes)

writeVector(intersecting_shapes ,"/Desktop/Allocation/testing12.shp")
```

can anyone help what I am doing wrong? there is no error in code

Comment: Why not use `sf::st_intersection(shapefile1, shapefile2)`?

Comment: @AllanCameron shapefiles are very big and sf::st_intersection takes too much time :(

Comment: any idea how can i do it? @AllanCameron

Comment: I don't have your shape files, so don't know what would be fast enough. Do you have a lot of these to do?

Comment: yep , files are more than 15 to 40 depends on user how many he wants to select , but about shapefile , each shapefile have :- approx 40,484 rows and 5 columns in it @AllanCameron. i used terra::intersect package its fast but i am facing problem mentioned above